# Pandas sparse dataframe multiplication

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, sparse-matrix, sparse-dataframe

I have two pandas sparse dataframes, big_sdf and bigger_sdf.

When I try to multiply them:

```
result = big_sdf @ bigger_sdf
```

I get an error:

```
"numpy.core._exceptions.MemoryError: Unable to allocate 3.6 TiB for an array with shape (160815, 3078149) and data type int64"
```

So I tried to convert these sparse dataframes to SciPy's csr matrices and multiply it, but the conversion doesn't succeed:

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
csr_big = csr_matrix(big_sdf)
csr_bigger = csr_matrix(bigger_sdf)
```

When I run the last row I get an error message:

```
"ValueError: unrecognized csr_matrix constructor usage"
```

It only happens for the bigger matrix, the smaller one is converted with success.

Any ideas? Maybe there's a Pandas native method to multiply sparse dataframes which I missed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `csr_matrix` does not "know" anything specific about 'sparse dataframes'.  `csr_matrix(big_sdf)` first does `np.as_array(big_sdf)`, or effectively `big_sdf.to_numpy()`.  Compare that for your two frames, and see what's different.

Comment: Actually, I should have first asked for FULL error message, or messages since you talk about two errors.

Comment: Provide a [mre]. Anyway, did you try ```big_sdf.sparse.to_coo() @ bigger_sdf.sparse.to_coo()```?